# WebServices in Java using Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jersey

We have tried to create sample webservices helloworld in Java using Jersey and Tomcat by following these links:

- http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

But while running the Application we are getting the error like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

my ‍‍‍`web.xml` file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Jersey</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>sample.hello.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

So please give me any suggestions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10009010/443515

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you copied all the Jersey downloaded files to the lib folder ?

It is giving `ClassNotFoundException` at `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`

Comment: I have already added all the jersey jars in the lib folder, Still it is showing the same error

Comment: It is working for me, I used the following jars
asm-3.1.jar
 jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
 jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
 jersey-client-1.11.jar
 jersey-core-1.11.jar
 jersey-json-1.11.jar
 jersey-server-1.11.jar
 jersey-servlet-1.11.jar
 jettison-1.1.jar
 jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Please specify the steps you followed

Comment: I followed the same steps as mentioned in the website. You can download the eclipse project from this [link](http://javablog.webs.com/RestfulDemo.zip)

Comment: I am working on calculator from this example:
http://www.jgeppert.com/2009/03/restful-web-services-jax-rs-mit-jersey/
Please give suggestions how do it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AurA - The dependency I was missing was jersey-servlet-.